# How can i change the jquery dialog background ,back color,header,footer and all

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I want to change the background color,image ,header,footer of jquery dialog.

How can I do this. Could some one give the code to solve this

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)

> ThemeRoller allows you to design custom jQuery UI themes for tight integration in your projects. To create a custom theme, select the Roll your own tab and tweak the settings. As you work, the UI components to the right will update to reflect your design and you can download your theme whenever you like.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at jquery UI theming:
http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

You can use the themeroller to create a custom theme or you could use a pre-ready theme from the gallery.